# UNIQUE index spanning multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-keys, unique-index

I have the following schema.  How do I ensure that all values in child are unique for a given child.group_id, child.type, and parent.status?  Please note the 1-to-1 relationship between parent and child.  If parent and child was one table, a simple UNIQUE index would work, however, I wish to keep the two tables separate. Ideally, stored procedures wouldn't be used, however, I am open to them if necessary.  I am using the latest version of MySQL.  Thank you

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS group (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  moreData VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (id) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parent (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  status VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  moreData VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (id) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS child (
  parent_id INT NOT NULL ,
  group_id INT NOT NULL ,
  type INT NOT NULL ,
  moreData VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (parent_id) ,
  INDEX fk_child_group1_idx (group_id ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT fk_child_parent
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id )
    REFERENCES parent (id )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_child_group1
    FOREIGN KEY (group_id )
    REFERENCES group (id )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: I don't get  what exactly should be unique. (Besides that, please try to keep the clutter out for questions. We don't need  5 lines of constraint when a simple addendum `refererences T(key)` suffices on the column declaration line. Try to provide a minimal example of the problem)

Comment: @JoSo child.group_id, child.type, and parent.status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something along these lines.

Create an overlapping constraint in "parent". (The column "id" is unique, so {id, any-other-column} must also be unique.)

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parent (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  status VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  moreData VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE (id, status) 
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Add the status column in "child".

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS child (
  parent_id INT NOT NULL ,
  parent_status VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  group_id INT NOT NULL ,
  type INT NOT NULL ,
  moreData VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
```

Primary key constraint doesn't *have* to change.

```
  PRIMARY KEY (parent_id) ,
  INDEX fk_child_group1_idx (group_id ASC) ,
```

Reference the pair of columns.

```
  CONSTRAINT fk_child_parent
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id, parent_status )
    REFERENCES parent (id, status )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_child_group1
    FOREIGN KEY (group_id )
    REFERENCES group (id )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION) ,
```

Whether you ought to cascade updates in fk_child_parent is application-dependent. Give that some thought.

And add a unique constraint on the set of columns you say should be unique.

```
  CONSTRAINT uq_child
    UNIQUE (group_id, type, parent_status)
    REFERENCES group (id)) 
 ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Yes, I suppose I would need to do something like this.  I would also need to move parent.moreData to a separate table (especially since it is more than one column) for normalization purposes.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create `before insert` trigger to do this verification, `check constraints` are not supported by mysql so that's not an option.